# Register-ScheduledTask with Description parameter failing

Tags: powershell, arguments

Very strange, I'm trying to register a scheduled task with a description but it always throws an error.

This works fine:

```
$Params = @{
    Execute  = 'Powershell.exe'
    Argument = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass 
                -File "\\Server\c$\Script.ps1"'
}
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction @Params
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action
$Params = @{
    InputObject = $Task
    TaskPath    = '\PowerShell scripts'
    User        = 'Domain.Net\Admin'
    Password    = 'Password'
}
Register-ScheduledTask @Params -TaskName 'Printer list' -Force
```

But the moment that I add a description by using intellisense from the ISE, like so:

```
Register-ScheduledTask @Params -TaskName 'Printer list' -Description "This is my description" -Force
```

It throws the following error:

```
Register-ScheduledTask : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super stupid of me, you have to define the **Description** with the `New-SheduledTask` Cmdlet:

```
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Description "This is my description"
```